# Same layout different content html

Tags: php, html, css, layout

Quite new to creating websites so not sure on everything, but i've been looking for a while on how to minimize the amount of html pages are in one website. As it just taking too much space. Every page has the same layout just different content, i know there is a way of just changing the content without making so many html pages but i've been looking and cant seem to find any kind of code that will do this. I know there has got to be loads of answers to this question but I must be wording it wrong when searching as i just cant seem to find anything. So basically i want to know if there is a way i can make one page for the layout and then one page for all the content and obviously when links are pressed the right content will be displayed?
Sorry if this is a stupid question, its just getting irritating not finding exactly what i need.

Comment: you mean a content management system like wordpress written in php?

Comment: You could consider storing the header and footer of your pages in a single PHP file - assuming both the header and the footers are constant throughout the website. Each webpage would then call the echo the header, display the content, then echo the footer. Any changes to the header/footer would affect the entire site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create layouts, you can use the include function to add the redudant parts of your page(header, footer, menu or sidebar).

For more informations, look [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/simple-layouts-with-php/) and [here](http://www.php.net/include)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too broad, but to give you a quick answer - people use AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) to fetch contents from a remote page and then they embed it into the current one.

That means you can either "fetch" static HTML, dynamic HTML (php, python, ruby etc), JSON and so on.

There are several ways to do this, but this should help you start googling or asking the right questions.

AJAX - jQuery - how to. Then if you're stuck again with **a real programming problem**, just drop a question to SO.